# Bloomberg Get ETF Constituents

Tags: programming, portfolio, bloomberg

I used the PortfolioDataRequest aspect of the Bloomberg API in C++; however, when attempting to request the portfolio of the TAIL US EQUITY (an ETF), it returns an invalid symbol.

I also tried using the portfolio id "H195151-74" but to no avail.

Comment: Leaving aside the Bloomberg API for the moment, does the Bloomberg terminal have data for this fund? What identifier (ticker) did you use?

Comment: @noob2 The Bloomberg terminal shows me the portfolio under the PORT <GO> command

Comment: Did you ask the help desk? They will not explain you c++ but there is nothing in the API that excel cannot do (in fact, excel is more versatile than c++).

Comment: I don't think constituents are available through the API for ETFs, only for indices. So you would have to manually download the holdings from PORT. You can double check with HELP HELP.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you just refer to Portfolio look-through in PORT? If so, that is the same as `TAIL US Equity MEMB`. That is not a portfolio data request. The `ID H195151-74` is just what PORT assigns to TAIL US Equity if you load it directly. I cannot comment on tickerized portfolios (these need extra enablement) but apart from that, in API, the only solution you have is BQL which you cannot use in C++ .

```
=BQL("members('TAIL US Equity',type='holdings')","id().weights")
```

Generally, there is `INDX_MEMBERS` but if you try that in `FLDS` you will see that it does not support any Equity tickers like @assylias explained as well (which means no ETFs like SPY, TAIL etc.). You can type `SPX Index FLDS DS325` in the command line to see what I mean. If you switch to an ETF, that field disappears because the filter is set to equity (which is not supported).

So I guess the easiest solution would be to automate an import from a sheet that pulls the ETF holdings via BQL. Or you ask your sales rep whether tickerized portfolios could do that or if they have some premium feed (data license) offering for holdings data.